# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un JQUERY/JS, una notificación en la pantalla?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, html5

Mi pregunta es la siguiente. Tengo una web que estoy desarrollando y estoy ante el siguiente problema que no consigo resolver. 
Hago consultas contra mysql con php y lo guardo en cookies los errores o consultas bien hechas, y quiero que el usuario en la pantalla le salga notificado que se ha completado correctamente. Para las notificaciones estoy utilizando el siguiente js/Jquery, está diseñado para ejecutarse cuando reciba un click de un id de un boton, pero quiero ejecutarlo cuando esta consulta se termina. Me podeis ayudar?

MI CÓDIGO PARA LA NOTIFICACIÓN

```
$(document).ready(function () {

"use strict";

var i = -1;
var toastCount = 0;
var $toastlast;

var getMessage = function () {
    var msgs = ['Ejemplo de notificación'];
    i++;
    if (i === msgs.length) {
        i = 0;
    }

    return msgs[i];
};


$('#newLista_alert').click(function () {
    var shortCutFunction = 'success';
    var msg = 'Preparada para meterle canciones';
    var title = 'Lista creada existosamente' || '';
    var $showDuration = $(300);
    var $hideDuration = $(1000);
    var $timeOut = $(2000);
    var $extendedTimeOut = $(500);

    var toastIndex = toastCount++;

    var addClear = $('#addClear').prop('checked');

    toastr.options = {
        closeButton: true,
        debug: false,
        newestOnTop: false,
        progressBar: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' || 'toast-top-right',
        preventDuplicates: false,
        onclick: null
    };

    toastr.options.showEasing = 'swing';

    toastr.options.hideEasing = 'linear';

    toastr.options.showMethod = 'fadeIn';

    toastr.options.hideMethod = 'fadeOut';



    var $toast = toastr[shortCutFunction](msg, title); // Wire up an event handler to a button in the toast, if it exists
    $toastlast = $toast;

    if (typeof $toast === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    if ($toast.find('#okBtn').length) {
        $toast.delegate('#okBtn', 'click', function () {
            alert('you clicked me. i was toast #' + toastIndex + '. goodbye!');
            $toast.remove();
        });
    }
    if ($toast.find('#surpriseBtn').length) {
        $toast.delegate('#surpriseBtn', 'click', function () {
            alert('Surprise! you clicked me. i was toast #' + toastIndex + '. You could perform an action here.');
        });
    }
    if ($toast.find('.clear').length) {
        $toast.delegate('.clear', 'click', function () {
            toastr.clear($toast, { force: true });
        });
    }
});

function getLastToast() {
    return $toastlast;
}
$('#clearlasttoast').click(function () {
    toastr.clear(getLastToast());
});
$('#cleartoasts').click(function () {
    toastr.clear();
});
});
```

Mi código de inserción en MYSQL

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['newLista'])){

$nombrelista = $_REQUEST['nombrelista'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];

require_once "../biblioteca.php";

$db = ConectaDb($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);    

$consulta="INSERT INTO lista_musica (nombre,usuario) VALUES (:lista,:usuario)";

$result=$db->prepare($consulta);

    if ($result->execute([":lista" => $nombrelista, ":usuario" => $usuario,])){
        setcookie('result_musica','0',time()+10);
        header ('location: ../../ui-musica.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "LISTA NO SE PUDO CREAR";
    }   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del php al acabar la consulta puedes hacer esto

```
echo '<script>document.getElementById("newLista_alert").click();</script>';
```

También puedes hacer el insert después del botón.
O utilizas [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'form_addMusic.php',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log(respuesta);
        $('#newLista_alert').click();
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: No funciona, me da un error al intentar ejecutarlo, En el inspector de google me sale esto. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at form_addMusic.php:5

Comment: Se me había colado el '#', pruebalo y si no te funciona sera porque no ha cargado el documento en el momento en que se hace la consulta. Lo que quieres hacer se haría con ajax, ahora edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo he probado cambiando comillas y quitándole el # que también me di cuenta de que sobraba. ¿Se hace con ajax dices?. Detallame un poco más eso si puedes porfa. Cambio a ajax si hace falta.

Comment: Con AJAX puedes realizar peticiones al servidor y obtener respuesta de este en sin necesidad de recargar la página web.

Comment: Hmm okaay, y en cuanto haga esa petición y me de un resultado puedo ejecutar el js de la notificación no?

Comment: Exacto, con success sabes que se ha ejecutado el insert correctamente y ya puedes mostrarle la notificación.

Comment: Okay, voy a hacer la consulta e intentarlo, al rato te comento, gracias

Comment: Hay alguna página del explique como usar y definir bien ajax para las consultas?

Comment: [Ejemplo ajax](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4309491-simplifica-tus-proyectos-con-jquery/4981961-el-metodo-ajax) esta por ejemplo, con buscar ajax jquery php te vas a encontrar muchos ejemplos explicados.

Comment: Muchas gracias hombre